# How to get Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate in typescript?

Tags: javascript, swift, typescript, date, timestamp

In Swift, I use the below line to get a [timeStamp](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1417376-timeintervalsincereferencedate).

```
let timeStampForUpload = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

I need to create an exact equivalent in typescript. How can I do that?

I have been offerd this answer:

```
let date = new Date('2001-01-01');
let timestamp = date.getTime()/1000;
```

The issue is that it does not output the same value as Apple's.

Comment: What have you tried so far? That code just gets the timestamp in `00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001`. It's just a simple date subtraction.

Comment: I tried looking for stuff in Date() but could not find anything, and I have not found any question on this @Alexander

Comment: @Alexander can you show how to do that?

Comment: I don't see anything in Apple's documentation on how strings are parsed, so '2001-01-01' might be treated as local or UTC. If you don't want to leave it to a particular implementation, much better to use specific values.

Comment: @Outsider Not unless you've shown any effort in trying to solve this problem for yourself. StackOverflow isn't a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
let date = new Date();
let timestamp = date.getTime();
```

since: 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001:

```
let date = new Date('2001-01-01');
let timestamp = date.getTime()/1000;
```

Apple:

```js
let coredate = new Date().getTime();
let unixdate = new Date( '2001/01/01' ).getTime();
let mactimestamp = ( coredate-unixdate )/1000;
```

Comment: Does this produce a timeStamp since: 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001? If no then no not this.

Comment: is the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970.

Comment: Can you include in the answer the full conversion to get the equivalent, then I mark as answer.

Comment: Hey so actually I find that it should be outputting: 582876615.62757, but instead, it outputted 978307200, how can this be fixed in teh calculation.

Comment: No, since: 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001 the result is 978307200. You can try it here: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: well it is not what apple outputs, how can I recreate what they do?

Comment: In Mac timestamp is the number of seconds since midnight, January 1, 1904, GMT

Comment: Ok how would I create that calculation?